# file_get_contents to url on the same server

Tags: php

I have two files on my server.
File `a.php`:

```
<?php 
die('this is my text');
?>
```

File b.php:

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://mysite.pl/a.php');
?>
```

But it's not working... I can't use `file_get_contents`, when the files are located on the same server, I don't know why.
PHP Info:

```
allow_url_fopen: ON
allow_url_include: OFF
```

When I try use the code from file b.php on difficult server - it working... ;/

Comment: when getting files locally, use the local file path instead. or did you want the results of `file_get_contents` to contain 'this is my text'?

Comment: Consult PHP manual on the subject (example #1) try that: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Please define "not working". Are there any error messages?

Comment: Try to `echo` the content :-)

Comment: @helmbert not errors, when i use var_dump() - I get string(0), but when i use this code on another server - I get string('this is my text')...

Comment: @user2180346 did you try/test my answer yet?

Comment: maybe the domain name "mysite.pl" is not resolvable inside your web server. Have you tried to run "ping mysite.pl" from a shell window inside the web server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using 127.0.0.1, however it won't work on a VirtualHost.

Answer (score -4):

You can try the relative path.

If `a.php` and `b.php` are in the same directory, do:

```
// b.php (If a.php is in the same directory)
file_get_contents('./a.php');
```

If `a.php` is in the upper directory:

```
// b.php (If a.php is in an upper directory)
file_get_contents('../a.php');
```

If `a.php` is in the root directory:

```
// b.php (If a.php is in the root directory)
file_get_contents('/a.php');
```